# Does mod_rewrite in subdirectories' .htaccess override higher levels?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to map my old directory structure to a new one. I have the following rule in my top-level .htaccess file, and it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog/archives/(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /archives/%1 [L,R=301]
```

As you can guess, this takes `http://example.com/blog/archives/00001.php` and redirects it to `http://example.com/archives/00001.php`.

But when I add these rewrite rules to the .htaccess file in the /blog directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule atom.xml$ /atom.xml [L,R=301]
```

the top-level redirect no longer works. If I move the rule in the /blog .htaccess file to the top-levle file both rules work. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `inherit` flag of the `RewriteOptions` directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Adding `RewriteOptions Inherit` to the subdirectory's .htaccess file fixed the problem.